# Jquery validator weird behaviour with remote

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a registration form which is using jQuery validator as:

```
$('reg_form').validate({
  ignore:"",
  rules : {
    user_name : {
      required :1,
      minlength :8,
      remote :"check_user_name.php"
    },
    password : {
      required :1,
      minlength :8,
    },
    firstname : {
      required :1,
    },
    lastname : {
      required :1,
    },
    email : {
      required :1,
    },
  }
});
```

It worked pretty well but the problem is remote. It never detects if the username is already in the DB.

The code in remote is as:

```
$uname = $_GET["user_name"];

$UserObj = new User();
echo $UserObj->checkUniqueUser($uname);
```

checkUniqueUser() will check if there is an user with the same name it will return false else true.

I got the URL from the request watch

```
http://project.localhost/check_user_name.php?user_name=admin
```

I hot linked the URL and it says false, since the admin is already there in the DB and if I change to something else it shows true (of course its not there in DB)

Can someone please help me on this ? Hope I was able to make it clear what I have done so far and what issue I am facing.

This is my function which I have in the User class.

```
public function checkUniqueUser($username){
      $return = true ;
      global $db ;
      $db->query("select iduser from user where 
      user_name = '".$this->cleanInput($username)."'");
      if($db->numRows() > 0 ){
        $return = false ;
      }
      return $return ;
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is in the `User` class method `checkUniqueUser`. Could you paste the code of that method? We won't be able to solve this if you don't. If you paste a valid user and it throws false, and with an invalid user throws true, then the problem is that the validations are incorrect, or are swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want an *output*, you need to `echo` `true` or `false` from your function, not `return`.  Technically, there's nowhere to `return`.

See [PHP `return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and [PHP `echo`](http://www.php.net/echo).

```
public function checkUniqueUser($username){
      $return = true ;
      global $db ;
      $db->query("select iduser from user where 
      user_name = '".$this->cleanInput($username)."'");
      if($db->numRows() > 0 ){
        $return = false ;
      }
      echo $return ;  // echo (output) true or false
}
```

Comment: Cool it worked !! I was banging my head for a while :)

Comment: Also read through other posts I may need to use echo json_encode(); I will try them out .

Comment: @user3228222, yes, the output must be valid JSON, however, AFAIK, I don't think it matters for boolean values.  The jQuery Validator also takes a string which would become the error message and this must be JSON.  (You must have a certain amount of rep to vote.)

Comment: @user3228222, you could always come back after reaching 15.