# jquery validate firing unhighlight function imediately after highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

despite my problem is similar [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903707/jquery-validate-is-firing-both-highlight-and-unhighlight-in-chrome)

the proposed solution did not work for me.
Let me explain what happens.
As the title suggests unhiglight is called right after highlight.

and this happens only under one scenario only:
**using remote method of email**.
If the ajax call returns true(after hitting the submit button)(email does not exist) error class is added and immediately replaced by valid class in the fields that are not filled(required)...

if I hit submit again the problem does not appear...if some fields are not filled error class is attached properly.

What differentiates first from second submit(and if email is not changed) is the fact  that ajax call for the email is not made.

So if ajax call is made(for the email) and returns true the above problem appears.
The code for the showerrors method found in the above Soverflow post does not help.

**I must emphasize that if I remove the remote method for the email the problem is fixed**

here is the code inside validate():

```
  $('#bizuserform').validate({
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
     
        if (errors) {
            
            var message = errors == 1 ? '1 field is miissing!!!' :  errors + ' fields are missing!!!';
           
            $("#error_general span").empty().html(message);
            $("#error_general").show();
        } else {
            $("#error_general").hide();
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
     
      if($(element).attr("id")=='staffclient_yes')
          {
            $('#staffclient_yes').parent().addClass(errorClass);   
          }
        
        
        if($(element).attr("id")=='medical')
          {
            $('#medical').parent().addClass(errorClass);   
          }
           $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
          },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
          if($(element).attr("id")=='staffclient_yes')
          {
            $('#staffclient_yes').parent().removeClass(errorClass);   
          }
           
          if($(element).attr("id")=='medical')
          {
            $('#medical').parent().removeClass(errorClass);   
          }
          $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);

         },
    onfocusout: false,
    submitHandler: function(form,event) {

      
        event.preventDefault();
      //ajax request here...ommited for brevity
        
          },
 
    rules:{
    name: {
        required: function () {
            return $('#coname').is(':blank');
        },
        normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
    },
    lastname: {
         required: function () {
            return $('#coname').is(':blank');
        },
        normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
    },
    coname: {
          required: function () {
            return $('#name,#lastname').is(':blank');
        },
        normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
    },
    buztype:{required:true 
   },
    med_spec:{
     required: function(element) {return $('#medical').is(':checked');}
      
         },
    password:{
      required:true,
      password:true,
      normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
  },
    address:{ required: true,
    normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
        },
    city:{ required: true,
    normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
        },
    municipality:{ required: true,
    normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}
        },
    email:{required: true,
           email: true,
           remote: {
           url: "email_validity.php",//if I remove the remote method here problem is fixed
           type: "post"
          },
           normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );}

        },
    phone:{required:true,
          normalizer: function( value ) { return $.trim( value );},
          digits: true,
          rangelength: [10, 14]
        
     },
    staff_to_client:{
  required: "#staf_eng:visible"
     }
    },
    messages:{
        buztype:'',
        staff_to_client:'',
        med_spec:'',
        coname:"",
         name:'',
    lastname:'',
    password:{required:""
   
     },

     address:'',
     city:'',
     municipality:'',
     email:{required:"",
           email:'not valid email',
           remote:'email allready exists.'
        },
     phone:{required:"",
     rangelength:'phonenumber messasge.',
     digits:'only digits here'
     },
     staff_to_client:{
  required: ""
     }
 }
    
});
```

Comment: You have a lot of customizations there.  What happens when you just use the default options?

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove all custom options except for the rules and messages and see what it does.  Then add each option or part of each option until you recreate the problem.  As it stands, it's impossible for anyone to help you without recreating the HTML, and since it's a `remote` issue, setting it up on a test server, with some unknown server-side code.

Comment: Οκ...will do it and mention what happens

Comment: .here is a fiddle first of all https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/vkLwpneh/36/  the problem DOES not appear when the server returns null(invalid that is)the problem appear when echo json_encode(''true)....in the fiddle I can only replicate the null case...I do not know how to return true from the link you see in the remote method so as to replicate the problem....if the server returns true the problems appears when onfocusout is set to false or the ajax request fails to send a response. But we must make the fiddle to return true to show you exactly the problem.

Comment: my server-side code is this..very simple: https://pastebin.com/zU49Q6Yt but it seems onfocusout:false creates problem,,,it does not make sense though why it would create the problem

Comment: but most important its behavior is erratic and appears even if the above condition are not present....meaning onfocusout:false and no response from the server on ajax call

Comment: it seems that email pending for validity plays a role in the problem

Comment: I am not sure if there could be a solution.  The plugin is designed with "asynchronous" `remote` so that it does not hang while waiting on the server.  There are about 1,000 SO questions about the `remote` method of this plugin and I don't think any deal with this complaint, and the "problem" itself is still unclear as described.  Regarding the timing of `unhighlight`, I don't understand why or how this is an issue in your situation.  What is undesirable about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233808/discussion-between-dimitris-papageorgiou-and-sparky).